# Moving a canvas element around on webpage

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a local web server on a raspberry pi that I am using as a kiosk for rotating photos.  I am also trying to include the coolclock.js script on the page which I do have working, but I would like the canvas that the clock lives in to move when the photo changes so it doesn't get burned in on the TV that the pi is hooked up to.  I cannot get the clock to move on the page though...

```
function rotateImages() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('clockid');
  alert(canvas.style.top);
  alert(canvas.style.left);
  if(last==1){
    document.body.style.backgroundImage='url('+preloads2.src+')';
    num=Math.floor(Math.random()*preloads.length);
    preloads1.src=preloads[num];
    last=2; 
    canvas.style.top = '0px';
    canvas.style.left = '0px';
  }

  else{
    document.body.style.backgroundImage='url('+preloads1.src+')';
    num=Math.floor(Math.random()*preloads.length);
    preloads2.src=preloads[num];
    last=1; 
    canvas.style.top = '500px';
    canvas.style.left = '500px';
  }
  }

var myVar=setInterval(function(){rotateImages()}, speed);
 </script>

<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="coolclock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="moreskins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </head>
 <body onload="CoolClock.findAndCreateClocks()">
 <canvas id="clockid" class="CoolClock::50::-4"></canvas>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The clock works, the images rotate, and the alerts show that the style.left and top are changing the way I would expect, but the clock doesn't budge.  Do I have to update or refresh something in order to activate the new position?  I've found lots of things that explain how to move elements around that are coded (i think) the same as I have, but no examples of canvases specifically - so maybe a canvas doesn't work this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that you canvas has style `position`, and its value should be `fixed`, `absolute` or `relative`, so the `style.left/right/top/bottom` would work. If you don't assign any position value to the canvas's style, it's default is `static`. And the `top, right, bottom, left` and `z-index` properties do not apply on elements whose position is `static`.

I've created a snippet to show how that works. You can find more from [MDN-style-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```js
var i;
var cv, ctx, grd;
for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
  cv = document.getElementById('move' + i);
  ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
  grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(75, 75, 10, 75, 75, 75);
  grd.addColorStop(0, 'red');
  grd.addColorStop(0.2, 'red');
  grd.addColorStop(0.4, 'yellow');
  grd.addColorStop(0.6, 'green');
  grd.addColorStop(0.8, 'blue');
  grd.addColorStop(1, 'purple');
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 150);
}


var last = false;
// Alter each canvas' top style to change its position.
setInterval(function(){
  var cv, ctx, grd;
  var top = last ? '300px': '';
  last = !last;
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    cv = document.getElementById('move' + i);
    cv.style.top = top;
  }

}, 1000);
```

```css
#move1 {}

#move2 {
  position: relative;
}

#move3 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="move1" width="150" height="150"></canvas><!-- position is default: static -->
<canvas id="move2" width="150" height="150"></canvas><!-- position is relative-->
<canvas id="move3" width="150" height="150"></canvas><!-- position is absolute -->
```

Comment: Perfect!  I still struggle with basic things like where to put code, I tried a few different things like changing the position attribute in my javascript, but once I just went with what you suggested inside the <style type="text/css"> portion of the page it's doing what I want. Thanks!